# Is there a way to make space twice as wide in VS editor visually? I.e. 2-space tab look like 4-space tab?

Tags: visual-studio, tabs

Is there a way to make 2-space tabs look as wide as 4-space tabs? I'm working on a project where they adopted 2-space tabs and use spaces for indentation, but it makes it difficult to distinguish among different depths in comparison to when using 4-space tabs. I can't convert the whole project to 4-space tabs.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to leave with that. Majority rules... This is a reason I am fighting for many years to use TAB as an indentation; simple rule: one level - one tab. And everyone can look at his favorite number of spaces per tab. You can try to hack your font (or find one?) that has a double-wide space. Check this out: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127074/what-fonts-are-out-there-that-are-designed-like-monospaced-fonts-but-arent-com

Comment: This might be what you want: [How to replace a character in a font with another character](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19554/how-to-replace-a-character-in-a-font-with-another-character)

Comment: I just read that editing existing fonts is not strictly legal, so considering this is for business not sure I want to go down that route.

Comment: You said: `I can't convert the whole project to 4-space tabs.` Do you mean - you are not allowed? Because it shouldn't be that hard...

Comment: We're working on a fork of a github project and we aren't going to push changes to code format in the main repo. So doing it locally, would cause a hell for any pulls or pushes from/to main repo.

Comment: Also changing of a font to have wider single spaces is suboptimal, because now that'd widen all spaces.

Comment: This would make a nice VS extension.